# passing variable from controller to vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

I want to recover from my controller function the average of the tasks of each projects
i try my way but it didn't work it show 0. any help guys? (the problem is in the project.vue ) 
this is the progress function which return the average of tasks of each project :

```
 public function progress($id){

$tasks=Task::where(['projet_id'=>$id])->get();
$x=0;
$i=0;
 foreach ($tasks as $task) {

    $x = $x + $task->progress;
    $i++ ;
  }
  $progress=$x/$i;
 return $progress;
  }
```

and this where i want to show the progress in project.vue:

```
 <tr v-for="projet in projets.data" :key="projet.id" >
<td @change="avancemant(projet.id)">
{{ parseInt(100 * progress ) }}%
<img :src="`/img/icon/verif.png`" style="width:15px; 
 v-if="`${parseInt(100*progress)}`==100" >
</img>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"   
id="progress" v-model="form.progress" 
aria-valuemin="`${parseInt(100*task.progress)}`":style=" 
{'width':`${parseInt(100*progress)}%`}" aria-valuemax="100">
 </div>
 </div>             
 </td>
```

and this is my project.vue script:

```
export default {
     data(){
         return{
      progress:'',
      projets:{},
      projet:{
          id:''
      },
      }}
    created(){
           }
    methods:{
     avancemant($id){
       axios.get('/api/progress/'+$id).then(({data})=>(this.progress =data.data));;
     },
    }
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log your data response object from axios?

Comment: show me nothing 
wen i test it using postman it show me the correct value

Comment: as in you aren't getting a response or it is returning an empty object? are you getting any errors?

Comment: empty object without errors

Comment: Sounds like the front end is working for the response. Could be a problem with your $id. What are you getting when you console.log $progress in your function?

Comment: exactly but i think my way of calling the avancment method is wrong or thing like that ?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with `@change="avancemant(projet.id)"` being off. The @change listens for `<select>` change events to bubble up to it and I don't see a nested `<select>` there. So `avancemant(projet.id)` is never being called. You're going to wan to implement some other logic so that it knows when to call `avancemant(projet.id)`

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues. A `<td>` tag wont fire a change event.

Even if you set it up to listen for an update you would run into an infinite loop issue.

You also need a way to store different progress values.

You could update the `projets` object like this:

```
avancemant(id){
  axios.get('/api/progress/'+id).then(
     ({data}) => (this.projets.data[id].progress = data.data)
  )
}
```

And call it from the mounted hook like this:

```
mounted () {
    Object.values(this.projets.data).forEach(function(x){
       this.avancemant(x.id)
    })
}
```

Of course, this will only fire once. Getting it to fire multiple times depending on the progress level is a different question.